# Get data from Search result(in a fragment) and update (other)fragments in the tab layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an Android Activity which has a tab-layout(with four fragments), and first fragment have a search function which search the data through a backend service. When it's success in getting data, then it should update other fragments with relevant data(recycler views and text views). But i cannot get an idea of how to work this thing around. I'll provide what i have done so far, let me know what am i doing wrong and how should i progress. A Code example is more than welcome.

What i have tried so far is within my search fragment, when the search function retrieves success data it will show a list item first of the users profile data. When on click on that item the whole activity will restart and the data is being binded to all the other fragments. What i need to achieve now is without refreshing nor restarting the whole activity, pass the data to relevant fragments and update the views.

***Collection Activity is the holder activity for my four fragments of the tab layout***

***In User Profile / Search Fragment***

```
/**this updates the view from  customer adapters data passing**/
public static UserProfileFragment newInstance(CustomerDTO commonCustomerDTOList, ArrayList<ContractDTO> commonContractDTOArrayList) {
    UserProfileFragment fragment = new UserProfileFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("CUS_DATA", commonCustomerDTOList);
    bundle.putSerializable("LOAN_DATA", commonContractDTOArrayList);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_profile, container, false);

   ...

    if (getArguments() != null) {

        CustomerDTO commonCustomerDTOList = (CustomerDTO) getArguments().getSerializable("CUS_DATA");
        setCustomerData(commonCustomerDTOList);

        NIC_NUMBER = ((CollectionActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).NIC_NUMBER;
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SharedValue.MYSESSION, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    return view;
}

/** set customer data from search result**/
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void setCustomerData(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
    if (customerDTO != null) {
        tvNic.setText(customerDTO.getNicNumber());
        txtFullName.setText(customerDTO.getTitle() + " " + customerDTO.getInitials() + " " + customerDTO.getLastName());
        txtMobile.setText(customerDTO.getMobileNo());
        tvAddress1.setText(customerDTO.getAddress().split("%")[0] + ",");
        tvAddress2.setText(customerDTO.getAddress().split("%")[1] + ",");
        tvAddress3.setText(customerDTO.getAddress().split("%")[2] + "");
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn_search_sUP:
            if (AppStatus.getInstance(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getActivity())).isOnline()) {
                /**
                 * Internet is available, Toast It!
                 */
                if (sSearchCriterion.equals("NIC (NEW/OLD)")) {
                    if (Validation.isValidNic(editTextSearch.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase())) {
                    } else {
                        editTextSearch.setError("Enter Valid NIC Number");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                showProgress();
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SharedValue.MYSESSION, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(SharedValue.MYSESSION_NIC_NUMBER, editTextSearch.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase());
                editor.putString(SharedValue.MYSESSION_MODULE_CODE, pProductType);
                editor.putString(SharedValue.MYSESSION_SEARCH_TYPE, catNormal);
                editor.apply();

                boolean isLoad = new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    String SearchMode = "";
                    int searchCriteriaType = SelectionCriteriaType.getSearchCriteriaType(sSearchCriterion);
                    if (searchCriteriaType == 1) {
                        SearchMode = SelectionCriteriaType.getSearchMode(SelectionCriteriaType.NIC);
                    } else {
                        SearchMode = SelectionCriteriaType.getSearchMode(SelectionCriteriaType.OTHER);

                    }
                    String CustomerCode = editTextSearch.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase();
                    if (!CustomerCode.isEmpty()) {
                        boolean isValidNic = Validation.isValidNic(CustomerCode);

                        switch (searchCriteriaType) {
                            case 1:
                                if (!sSearchCriterion.equals("NIC (NEW/OLD)")) {
                                    isValidNic = true;
                                    getLoanDetails(pProductType, "1", String.valueOf(searchCriteriaType), CustomerCode);
                                } else {
                                    getLoanDetails(pProductType, catNormal, String.valueOf(searchCriteriaType), CustomerCode);
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                isValidNic = true;
                                getLoanDetails(pProductType, SearchMode, String.valueOf(searchCriteriaType), CustomerCode);
                                break;
                        }
                        if (isValidNic) {
                        } else {
                            hideProgress();
                            editTextSearch.setError("Enter Valid NIC Number");
                        }

                    } else {
                        hideProgress();
                    }
                    hideProgress();
                    this.getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                }, 8000);

            } else {
                /**
                 * Internet is NOT available, Toast It!
                 */
                Toasty.error(this.getActivity(), "Please Connect to Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}

   ...

private void getLoanDetails(String moduleCode, String searchMode, String searchType, String searchCode) {
    System.out.println("call loan details...");
    CommonUtils.hideKeyboardFrom(this.getActivity(), view);

    ArrayList<ContractDTO> contractVehicleDTOArrayListClear = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CustomerDTO> customerDTOArrayListClear = new ArrayList<>();

    CustomerAdapter customerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(this.getActivity(), customerDTOArrayListClear, contractVehicleDTOArrayListClear, searchCode, moduleCode);
    listViewCustomerList.setAdapter(customerAdapter);
    customerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    try {
        showProgress();
        String param59 = moduleCode + "|" + searchMode + "|" + searchType + "|" + searchCode;

        new ISOConverter(new RResponce() {
            @Override
            public void get61and62Response(String res1, String res2) {
                if (res1.trim().isEmpty() || res2.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    CommonAlert.showAlertFailure(getActivity(), "No Details Found...");
                    search_result_card.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    CustomerDTO customerDTO = null;
                    if (sSearchCriterion.equals("BR NUMBER")) {
                        customerDTO = new CustomerDTO(res1, "");
                    } else {
                        customerDTO = new CustomerDTO(res1);
                    }

                    ArrayList<ContractDTO> contractDTOArrayList = new ContractDTO().getObjectArrayList(res2);
                    ArrayList<CustomerDTO> customerDTOArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    customerDTOArrayList.add(customerDTO);

                    CustomerAdapter customerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(getActivity(), customerDTOArrayList, contractDTOArrayList, searchCode, pProductType);
                    listViewCustomerList.post(() -> {
                        listViewCustomerList.setAdapter(customerAdapter);
                        customerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    });
                    if (customerAdapter.getCount() > 0) {
                        hideProgress();
                        search_result_card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        setCustomerData(customerDTO);
                    }
                    hideProgress();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void get39Response(String responseCode) {
                System.out.println(responseCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void get63Response(String error) {
                System.out.println(error);
                if (!error.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    new ShowMessageAsync(getActivity(), error, ShowMessageAsync.FAILED).execute();
                }

            }
        }).convertToISO(
                this.getActivity(),
                MTITransaction.GET_CALL,
                MTITransaction.MTI_GET,
                ISOProcessCode.TRANS_CODE_LOAN_SEARCH,
                "null", param59, "");


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

***Customer Adapter***

```
Context mContext;
List<CustomerDTO> customerDTOList;
LayoutInflater inflater;
String NicNumber;
String moduleCode;
ArrayList<ContractDTO> contractDTOArrayList;
UserProfileFragment userProfileFragment;

public CustomerAdapter(Context mContext, List<CustomerDTO> customerDTOList, ArrayList<ContractDTO> contractDTOArrayList, String NicNumber,String moduleCode) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.customerDTOList = customerDTOList;
    this.contractDTOArrayList = contractDTOArrayList;
    this.NicNumber = NicNumber;
    this.moduleCode = moduleCode;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

}
...
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
 ...

    holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CollectionActivity.class);
 //            Intent intent = new Intent("Pass Searched Data");
        // Pass all data arrearsList
//            intent.setAction("Pass Searched Data");
        intent.putExtra(DataparsingValue.VARIABLE_NIC_NUMBER, NicNumber);
        intent.putExtra(DataparsingValue.VARIABLE_CUS_DATA, customerDTOList.get(position));
        intent.putExtra(DataparsingValue.VARIABLE_LOAN_DATA, contractDTOArrayList);
        intent.putExtra(DataparsingValue.MODULE_CODE, moduleCode);

 //            intent.putExtra(DataparsingValue.VARIABLE_LOAN_WITH_VEHICLE_DATA, contractVehicleDTOArrayList);
        // Pass all data flag
        // Start SingleItemView Class
        mContext.startActivity(intent);

    });

    return convertView;
}
```

***DownPayment Fragment***
    //update the view using

```
 public static DownPaymentFragment newInstance(CustomerDTO commonCustomerDTOList, ArrayList<ContractDTO> commonContractDTOArrayList) {
    DownPaymentFragment fragment = new DownPaymentFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("CUS_DATA", commonCustomerDTOList);
    bundle.putSerializable(DataparsingValue.VARIABLE_LOAN_WITH_VEHICLE_DATA, commonContractDTOArrayList);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

***Receipts Fragment***
    //Update the list using

```
public static ReceiptingFragment newInstance(CustomerDTO commonCustomerDTOList, ArrayList<ContractDTO> commonContractDTOArrayList) {
    ReceiptingFragment fragment = new ReceiptingFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(DataparsingValue.VARIABLE_CUS_DATA, commonCustomerDTOList);
    bundle.putSerializable(DataparsingValue.VARIABLE_LOAN_DATA, commonContractDTOArrayList);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

I expect to Load the data from Search results to the Tab layout's relevant fragments without restarting the Whole activity.

Comment: Easy, use a shared ViewModel obtained from the Activity as the ViewModelStoreOwner, so that you can put a LiveData of the "searched items" in that ViewModel, observe it in the fragments, and then when network call finishes and you update LiveData, all fragments will update automatically. See [Google I/O 2017 introduction of Android Architecture Components](https://youtu.be/FrteWKKVyzI) for more info. Maybe also check [this video](https://youtu.be/eHjHlujp3Tg?t=1663) although it's a bit more bloated; and this codelabs: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#0

Comment: What is the possibility of achieveing what i need without the use of MVVM architecture?

Comment: You'd have to do the exact same thing as ViewModel + LiveData, just without ViewModel and without LiveData. You could potentially write something that works in a very similar manner and therefore solves the same problem. For example, a retained fragment that stores the data and exposes changes via Observer Pattern (via listeners) could potentially have similar behavior.

Comment: Or just ditch the retained fragment and write the data into Room directly which can then expose the data as `LiveData<List<T>>` to all fragments.

Comment: Overall, you should not be using `arguments` bundle for sending *data*. You can send IDs, selected filters, etc, but you shouldn't send data you fetch from the network - especially not lists of it. You won't be able to update them.